# Yii file upload $_FILE is empty

Tags: php, image, yii, upload

I am trying to upload a image by a form to my Model. I am using Yii 1.1

The model doesn't contain in database the column "image", so I have created the attribute in the model like this

```
public $image;
```

I have added in rules the following

```
array('image', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg,gif,png', 'allowEmpty'=>true),
```

In the view I added to the form the htmlOption `array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')`, while for the file upload:

```
<th><?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'image'); ?></th>
<td><?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'image');?></td>
<th><?php echo $form->error($model, 'image');'>'?></th>
```

I see the button for uploading the picture, when I press the button the action of my controller is called but if I make a log for showing the $_POST and/or $_FILES i got this:

Log from the $_FILES

```
2016/07/07 18:18:12 [info] [application] FILE : 

Array
(
)
```

Log that I receive from the $_POST

```
[Puntointeres] => Array
    (
        [Name] => My Name
        [Description] => What ever
        ......
        [image] => 
    )
```

Any help?

Comment: Did you look at the generated html to make sure that the `enctype` attribute is actually set? given that your `image` input shows up in $_POST, either you're not building the form correctly, or something's mangling it.

Comment: The input field should be $form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput()

Comment: Hi,
I'm using Yii 1.1 so I dont have the function $form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related with the SubmitButtonAjax that was serializing the fields and the file field was converted to a string.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you forgot to set the enctype:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
```

Also your field is incorrect, it should be:

```
$form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput()
```

Also remember Yii does not send the value of the image in $_POST. Through $_POST it sends the hidden field it generates while using inputFile.

Comment: Hi,
I'm using Yii 1.1 so I dont have the function $form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput(); 

Also I have the 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data' option in my form.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Did you check your html generated in Developer tool? I has `enctype` or not .
If not then add this in your form options.

```
'htmlOptions' => array(
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ),
```

Also you have to call `CUploadedFile` to get uploaded file info

use this link to upload a file in `yii`.http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model/

Info about `CUploadedFile` file http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile

Comment: Hi,
My form has the    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', I know I have to use the CUploadedFile but the problem is that the file doesnt arrive to the controller. Seems a form issue.

As I tried with Postman to send the form info to my Controller and I saw in my low the $_FILES with the image.